# Adding $and and $or queries to a structure for a MongoDB query - must be a non empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to combine multiple queries together into an object: the user can build the queries from preselected options and select either the and or the or operator. The queries are all outputted correctly but when put them into the object I get "Error: $and/$or/$nor must be nonempty array".

E.g. Let's say we have query a AND b AND c AND d AND e
the output should be: {$and[a,$and:[b,$and:[c,$and:[d,e]]]]}
this is so that if they select another operator, the operation still remains the same

Here is the code:

```
function nestOps(ops, queries) {
  let queryObj = {};
  if (ops.length > 1) {
    let querySet = {};
    querySet[`$${ops[ops.length - 1]}`] = [queries[ops.length - 1], queries[ops.length]];
    for (let i = ops.length - 2; i > 0; i--) {
      let next = {};
      next[`$${ops[i]}`] = querySet;
      querySet = {};
      let nextIdx = i - 1;

      if (nextIdx > 0) {
        querySet[`$${ops[nextIdx]}`] = [queries[i], next];
        i--;
      }
      else {
        querySet = next;
      }
    }


    queryObj[`$${ops[0]}`] = [querySet, queries[0]];
  }
  else {
    queryObj[`$${ops[0]}`] = [...queries];
  }
  return queryObj;
}
```

I have tried doing it through recursion however, my stack is pretty bloated (even with the stack size increased) and I cannot see how use the tailing method ("return nextCall()") as I have to return the previous query andded or orred and I can't really do that without an assignment first.

Here is the console output:

```
Output Object
$and: Array(2)
0:
  $and: Array(2)
  0: {questions: {…}}
  1:
   $and: // could be an error here but, I don't understand why
   $and: Array(2)
    0: {$or: Array(2)} //this happens due to a query, it is not an error
    1: {questions: {…}}
Operators
["and", "and", "and", "and"]

Queries
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {questions: {…}}
  1: {completedAt: {…}}
  2: {questions: {…}}
  3: {$or: Array(2)}
  4: {questions: {…}}
```

Comment: Why not `{$and: [all the options here]}` instead of nested and? I am not sure if that is a valid `$and` operation.

Comment: Hmm, I should've thought of that earlier, I'll try it and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it works fine, thanks.

Comment: Is it okay if I create separate answer for this? It would help me grow my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating nested `$and` you can simplify it using a single `$and`.

```
{ property: { $and: [ {filter}, {filter} ] }}
```